# How can I bind C-. in Emacs launched with -nw?

Tags: emacs

I recently installed jedi from el-get master branch.
jedi binds C-. for jedi:key-goto-definition but it's only working in X mode. It fails to bind when launched with -nw(no X) mode in both Emacs23 and Emacs24.

So, I tested simple binding in *scratch* buffer and then evaluated by C-x C-e.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-.") 'find-name-dired)
```

It worked well in X mode, but failed in no x mode(-nw).
Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance,

---

Edited

Here are some results of `C-h k` `C-.` after installing above command:

```
$ emacs -nw -q (without X)
```

> . runs the command self-insert-command, which is an interactive
>   built-in function in `C source code'.
>
> It is bound to many ordinary text characters.
>
> (self-insert-command N)

```
$ emacs -q (With X)
```

> C-. runs the command find-name-dired, which is an interactive
>   autoloaded Lisp function in `find-dired.el'.
>
> It is bound to C-..
>
> (find-name-dired DIR PATTERN)

Comment: you're right. it's duplicate. But I don't get the answer how to let my terminal recognize C-. rather than .(dot).

Comment: You haven't said which terminal emulator you're using, so how can anyone give you an exact answer to that?

Comment: New users should use Emacs in a graphical window.  Using it in a terminal opens yourself up to heaps of problems, which from the nature of your question, you are in no position to solve.

Comment: @phils GNOME Terminal 3.4.1.1(ubuntu 12.04). Because I thought the problem is in Emacs, not in terminal, I didn't say about terminal I'm using.

Comment: @event_jr Can you give me an answer for this question? or give me some hint or url... I often use emacs via ssh without no X forwarding. And I know Emacs with X is good because I've been using it since 2004. I just want to know why C-. doesn't work and which config should I change.

Comment: C-. does not work in terminals in general, because in ASCII there are only 32 control codes (0 to 31), assigned to C-@ to C-_ (in ASCII order ie. the control key masks bit 6).

Comment: Some emulators *do* provide enhanced keyboard support (for instance xterm provides options for additional key sequences), but it's certainly on a case by case basis. I'd suggest checking the Gnome Terminal manual for starters, but it might well be unable to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The terminal can't represent `C-.`. Find another key sequence and use ut, e.g. `C-c .`.